# where is keychains of my lost user account

Tags: macos, user-account, keychain

I lost my user in Mountain Lion and I forced to create a new user account.
I access to my previous user's folders now.
How can I find my previous keychains? I need to recover them and add into my new keychains.

Regards

Comment: keyhains are locked with the previous user password!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login keychain is in `/Users/username/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`. If the Library folder is hidden, you can select it with shift-command-G.

You can import the keychain to the current account by just opening it.